# iPhone client with a python socket

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, sockets, string

i am creating a python server socket that sends data to the client reguarding files status... what i have is a list containing dictionaries:

```
[{'Status': '[2,5%]', 'File': 'SlackwareDVD.iso'},
 {'Status': '[21,8%]', 'File': 'Ubuntu_x86.iso'}]
```

the socket, when asked, sends this data, obviously it is sent as a string type.. i was trying to figure out how i could pass this data in OBJC in corrispective NSarray and NSDictionaries...

anyone have a clue?? hints?? :D
Thanks

PirosB3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems perfectly suited for [JSON](http://json.org/). On the python side use any of the popular json libraries - for example, [simplejson](http://www.undefined.org/python/) - to convert your python data to json, and on the iPhone side use an iPhone json library to convert it to local data representations. [Here's an article](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) that shows how to do that.

Comment: great, did it in JSON at the end

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to an XML property list and Cocoa will do the rest.

Comment: Correct. XML, JSON, any **standard** format (not Python's `str` since that's language-independent, nor uniquely parseable) would be suited for this.

Comment: This is so genious... why didn't i think of it? i have always done it do get around situations as these!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A binary way to transport common types is using the [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/) protocol which is available for the iPhone [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hessiankit/). I'm not sure what the status of the python implementations are, I can find two ([1](http://hessian.caucho.com/#Python), [2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hessianpy/))

Using it makes it very easy to encode and decode messages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the python codebase, generating an XML Property List is trivial from Python.

See Understanding [XML Property Lists](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/UnderstandXMLPlist/UnderstandXMLPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH6-SW1) in the Apple documentation for more information.

I would be surprised if someone hasn't already written something that'll convert Python property lists into NSDictionary compatible XML property lists.